# modem and two routers configuration

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, lan, home-networking

I'm struggling with my new network setup. My configuration is:

- Modem
- router1 (dlink 645) connected to the modem through WAN port
- router2 (dlink 655) connected to the router 1 LAN to LAN
  Both routers are wifi-routers.

I followed this procedure:

1. set router2 IP to 192.168.80.2 (router1 IP is 192.168.80.1)
2. disabled DHCP and UPnP in router2
3. conected routers LAN to LAN

Now I can manage both routers through network. Devices connected to router1 works fine. Devices connected to router2 can connect to internet through wifi (in both routers), but not through LAN.
I've tried several ping commands from computer connected to router2 with this results:

- ping to first router OK
- ping to second router OK
- ping to any web NOT OK
- ping to any device connected to router 1 NOT OK

Although I can't ping devices connected to router1, I see them in the network  (from windows configuration and also from router config status)

I can provide additional info, just don't know what is relevant. Any ideas?

EDIT:

[ipconfig router1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzsq8mA--lZSQmlURVU5ZEVQbXM/view?usp=sharing)

[ipconfig router2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzsq8mA--lZSUUZlZm12MHZoTDg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Connect to R1 with cable, run "ipconfig /all"(windows)/"ifconfig"(mac/linux) and copy the results, Move cable to R2 and do it again. Then add results to your question.

Comment: I've added both ipconfig outputs.

Comment: Thanks. Both look perfect, DHCP is working as it should. The fact that pings from client through R2 and hitting R1 work would mean usually it all would. Seems like its selectively blocking. It shouldnt be this, but just in case can you disable the firewall on R2 and reboot it?

Comment: My firewall is disabled already I think. [my firewall setting](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzsq8mA--lZSLVlrbUw3Wm1ta3c/view?usp=sharing)